# Procedure or function 'sp_ConfigEntry' expexts parameter '@key1' which was not supplied

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I am getting this error pls help i am a rookie in VB

```
Public Shared Function GetKeyValue(ByVal key As String, ByVal isactive As Boolean) As String

Dim s As String

Using db As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.WSMplannet)

db.Open()

Using cmdkey As New SqlCommand("sp_ConfigEntry", db)

cmdkey.Parameters.Add("@key1", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = key

cmdkey.Parameters.Add("@Isactive", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = isactive

s = cmdkey.ExecuteScalar()

End Using

End Using

Return s

End Function
```

and procedure is this

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_ConfigEntry]

@key1 varchar(50),

@Isactive bit

AS

BEGIN

select VALUE from wsm_Config_Entry where [KEY]=@key1 and [ISACTIVE]=@Isactive

END
```

**table(wsm_Config_Entry) structure is 
ID  int,
KEY varchar,
VALUE   varchar,
DATE    date,
ISACTIVE    bit,**

Comment: error msg is very explicit

Comment: The procedure you call is named `sp_ConfigEntry` whereas the procedure name you cite is `sp_GetLeaseOfTenant`... ?

Comment: This doesn't look like C#. Is it VB.NET?

Comment: Its not c#, You must be aware that you are using vb.net.

Comment: As a side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Answer (score 2):

You have to set command type as StoredProcedure - C# code:

```
cmdkey.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: i don't have the  Reputation points 15 once i get it will change automatically !!